# JavaScript. 10%5 === 0 --> false?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, foreach

Please help to find mistakes in my code:

```js
function multipleOfIndex(array) {
    return array.forEach( item => console.log(item%array.indexOf(item) === 0) )
}
    
console.log(multipleOfIndex([68, -1, 1, -7, 10, 10])) // false, true, false, false, false, false
```

obviously, I was expecting

```
console.log(multipleOfIndex([68, -1, 1, -7, 10, 10])) // false, true, false, false, false, true
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you used your debugger? If not, **why not**?

Comment: yes, my bad. map()

Comment: @Roman nevermind, i missed that you were logging inside the forEach also. Anyway, the issue is that `indexOf` returns the *first* index. So 10 first appears at index 4. 10 % 4 = 2, which logs false. This happens for both 10s.

Comment: Thank you, friend, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is relying on indexOf when more than one value is the same in the array - `array.indexOf(10)` is always `4`, see the extended log here:

```js
function multipleOfIndex(array) {
    return array.forEach( item => console.log(item,array.indexOf(item),item%array.indexOf(item) === 0) )
}
    
console.log(multipleOfIndex([68, -1, 1, -7, 10, 10])) // false, true, false, false, false, false
```

The solution is to use the forEach `index` parameter (2nd one)
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```js
function multipleOfIndex(array) {
    return array.forEach( (item,idx) => console.log(item%idx === 0) )
}
    
console.log(multipleOfIndex([68, -1, 1, -7, 10, 10])) // false, true, false, false, false, false
```

Answer (score 1):

The [indexOf] method returns the first index of a given element that can be found in the array. If it does not exist, it returns - 1.
So the [indexOf] value of the last 10 is 4.